# Empty value when opening

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2, angularjs-select2

I want to use [select2 with Angular](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2), and sometimes it gets "empty" value when opening the select. I do not know why this happens.

Check how it looks like:

[image]

But, sometimes it works perfectly:

[image]

I really do not know why it happens this way. Here is my directive code:

```
<div class='form-group' ng-show="items && items.length > 0">
<ui-select ng-model="selectedItem" on-select="onChange($item);" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
        {{selectedItem[fillable]}}
    </ui-select-match>

    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in items | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind="item[fillable]"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
</div>
```

This is how I instantiate it:

```
<strainer-select
        items="campaigns"
        selectedItem="campaignSelected"
        handler="onCampaignFilterChanged"
        placeholder="Filtre por campanha"
        fillable="campaign"
    ></strainer-select>
```

Does anyone have ever seen this happens?

Any help is very appreciate.

Thank you all.

Comment: Inspect the live css in browser dev tools for clues

Comment: can you provide plnkr link for same?

Comment: Here it is:
https://embed.plnkr.co/YcWP4h6QbPLIoxakf4nW/

Also, I notice something very strange: when you resize the window, the problem occurs. If you refresh the page, the problem goes away. But if the user resizes the window, the problem occur. Really strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a bug of the directive itself. The problem seems to be with directive's input inside it. So a workaround is to add style to force 100% width.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.0.3" data-semver="2.0.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link data-require="select2@3.4.5" data-semver="3.4.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.5/select2.css" />
    <link data-require="select2@3.4.5" data-semver="3.4.5" rel="stylesheet" href="./select.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.5" data-semver="1.2.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ngSanitize@*" data-semver="1.3.15" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-select2@0.0.4" data-semver="0.0.4" src="./select.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      .ui-select-container input{
        width:100% !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-app="offersApp">
      <div ng-controller="myController">
        <strainer-select items="campaigns" selecteditem="campaignSelected" handler="onCampaignFilterChanged" placeholder="Filtre por campanha" fillable="campaign"></strainer-select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="strainerSelect.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```